# uso de la etiqueta form , atributo action

Tags: python, django, web

estoy aprendiendo a usar formularios en html pero parece que estoy haciendo algo mal

tengo este codigo html

```
<form action="/buscar/" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="producto">
    <input type="submit" value="Buscar">
</form>
```

el formulario se encuentra en la url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/busquedaProductos/`
se supone que al llenar el formulario y enviarlo me debe de llevar a

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/buscar/
```

como espesifica el artibuto 'action', pero en su lugar me lleva a

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/buscar/
```

pagina la cual no existe, como puedo lograr que me lleve a la url que quiero?, estoy usando django por cierto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard code

```
<form action="/app/buscar/" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="producto">
    <input type="submit" value="Buscar">
</form>
```

Si tienes configurado el nombre para la vista que recibe el formulario.
Tendrías algo asi. Esto es mejor a la hora de renombrar tus urls.

Suponiendo una app "busqueda".

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('busqueda.views',
    url(r'^$', view="buscar", name="busqueda_buscar"),
)
```

Template

```
<form action="{% url 'busqueda_buscar' %}" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="producto">
    <input type="submit" value="Buscar">
</form>
```

Comment: muchas gracias amigo !